# Node.JS application no longer run with error "Cannot use import statement outside a module "

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I coded a Node.js application a year ago that ran fine.  But today when I try to run it using the command "node app.js",  I get the error message

```
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: the package.json not including `"type": "module"`